# Can I ingest zipped data using Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am trying to ingest data to Elasticsearch.

The data is located in a shared folder.  If possible I want to delete the zip file once I ingested it to Elasticsearch.

It is a .zip file which unzips to a big single file with a format looking like this:

```
#ReferenceID    123das
#FamilyID       abc
#ArchiveDate    1483237892226   (datetime in millisecond epoch)
#SenderID       user1 
#RecipientID    user2 
#RecipientID    user3   (notice there are more than 1 RecipientID)
#Content        
This is secret content of the document, and it is not encrypted. 
#EndDoc

#ReferenceID    123das/1  (The "/1" means 1st attachment)
#FamilyID       abc        
#ArchiveDate    1483237892227   (datetime in millisecond epoch)
#SenderID       user1 
#RecipientID    user2 
#RecipientID    user3   (notice there are more than 1 RecipientID)
#Content        
This is the secret attachment content  
#EndDoc

#ReferenceID...
...
#EndDoc 

...multiple of these until End of File
```

Basically each

```
#ReferenceID... 
...
#EndDoc
```

Is representing a document to be ingested into Elasticsearch

My question is could this be done using Logstash and Beats?  How would I go about doing this? Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash's file{} input cannot handle a zipped file.  See the [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1817).

Filebeat can't either... yet!  See [this PR](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/2227), which seems to working its way through.

Just FYI, the s3{} input can.

Comment: Thanks Alain! I'll take a look at the s3